# regex to match numbers x1, x2, ..., xN

Tags: regex, numbers

The string is in the following format:

> "some text 1234, 45, 3423, 123 some
>   text 11, 12"

Is it possible to write regex which returns two matches:

> 1234, 45, 3423, 123 
>  11, 12

I write this one

> [0-9]+[\s]*[,]?[\s]*

and obviously it matches each number with a comma, so i get 6 matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression

```
\d+(?:,\s\d+)*
```